# Proving that a series is white noise, but not IID

Tags: time-series, self-study, iid, white-noise

I have this problem that I'm struggling to solve

Be $\left\{ Z_t \right\} \sim N(0,1)$ a stochastic process and let:

$$X_t = \begin{cases}
            Z_t & \text{if $t$ is even }\\
      \left( Z_{t-1}^2 - 1\right) /\sqrt{2}& \text{if $t$ is odd}
         \end{cases}$$

Prove that $\left\{ X_t \right\}$ is a white noise with mean $0$ and variance $1,$ but not IID.

Well, I could prove that the mean is 0 and the variance is 1 without much trouble. But I can't prove that $\operatorname{Cor} \left( X_{t}, X_{t+h} \right) = 0$ for all $t, h \in \mathbb{N}$. In fact, I can't even think how can I do this without knowing if the $Z_t$s are independent or not.

Any help or hints are appreciated. I'm very stuck here and I feel I'm missing some very basic knowledge.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the author of the question intended for you to assume that the $Z_t$s are independent.  You can then use the fact that $Z_t$ and $Z_t^2$ are independent and work from there.